# Github GraphQL API gives different values compared to what we see on the repo page

Tags: graphql, github-api

I'm trying to retrieve last commit and the number of releases for a public repo using Github API v4, following is my query:

```
 {    
    repository(owner: "tensorflow", name: "tensorflow") {
       id
       name
       releases {
          totalCount
       }
      pushedAt
    }
  }
```

The output that I get is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnk0NTcxNzI1MA==",
      "name": "tensorflow",
      "releases": {
        "totalCount": 49
      },
      "pushedAt": "2018-03-21T03:28:59Z"
    }
  }
}
```

The API returns number of releases as 49, but if you check the [repo page](http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow), the number of releases at this time is 51.
Any idea why these two values are different? How do you retrieve the values seen in the repo page?

Also the datetime returned by `pushedAt` gives a different time, is there a way to retrieve last commit time in default branch?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the release number:

- the 50th one is a *pre-release* one and might not be counted
- the 51th one is less than 8 hours old, so there could be a cache effect.

Regarding the pushedAt time, check if there is a difference due to time shift (UTC vs. another time)